# The meaning of « à + infinitif »

Tags: grammaire

> Nous sommes toujours en première ligne, à risquer nos vies.
>
> Nous sommes assis autour d'une table, à boire du vin.

The precise meaning of « à » in instances like these eludes me. I suppose that it is different from using « pour ».

Comment: On peut remplacer _à_ par _en train de_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be a translation could help you figure it out, if you're a native English speaker ? I'll give this a shot :

> We're still in the front line, risking our lives.
>
> We're seated at a table, drinking wine.

Here, "à" is just used to convey a sense of simultaneity to both actions, whereas "pour" would mean that we're seated at a table **in order to** drink wine (in which case I'd recommend an AA meeting asap).

Comment: Hi. Do they have the same meanings as "en risquant" and "en buvant"?

Answer (score 0):

A late answer here, but it occurs to me that this construction, i.e. "à + infinitive", crops up when the present participle is unavailable, after verbs evoking states rather than actions.
In other words, you might say, "il a réussi à venir, en risquant sa vie", but not "à risquer..." or "nous écoutons le concert, en buvant du vin" but not "à boire...".
The "à + infinitive" sequences seem to provide a development, or a gloss of the main clause to the left.